# Using CMake to find an OS package

Tags: cmake, mosquitto

I've done due diligence and googled around for this, but I can't seem to find an answer.  Sorry in advance if the answer is obvious.

Our source tree and unit tests are built using CMake.

The unit tests, when run, require a specific version of a Linux 3rd-party package (in this case, the `mosquitto` broker binary to be installed).  The source tree does not link against the `mosquitto` broker binary, but the unit tests need it when they are run.

Is there a way to use CMake to enforce that a specific version of the OS package `mosquitto` be installed?

For reference, here is the Fedora package required for success:

`mosquitto.x86_64                        1.5.3-1.fc27`

Comment: What does it mean that your unit test needs mosquitto broker binary? As in it wants to execute it but it has to be version 1.5.3-1.fc27?  CMake could use execute_process to call rpm to query the installed package and then parse the output to verify the package and error out if it was the wrong version.  But that would only happen when running cmake not when you run the actual tests.

Comment: I think something similar to that should work.  I did not know about execute_process.  Thanks!